# C# Run command in CMD

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a Windows form application to manipulate with cmd command.And its work for command like "ipconfig" or "dir" when i write command "netsh" nothing happens.Here is my code:

```
        string command = textBox2.Text;//Parsing command from textbox
        string text = string.Empty;//Creating empty variable
        Process cmd = new Process();//Creating process
        cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";//Set filename to cmd.exe
        cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + command;
        cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;//Redirect standard output
        cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmd.Start();
        StreamReader sr = cmd.StandardOutput;
        text = sr.ReadToEnd();//Writing output to string
        textBox1.Text = text;//Writing output to textbox
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are you actually trying to do? If you use `netsh` as a command without arguments, it will expect you to enter more text, as it provides an interactive command prompt in that case. If you use `netsh` with arguments, it should work fine. Please fix your question so it includes a [mcve], along with a detailed explanation of what the code does, what you want it to do instead, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: `netsh` is a program in its own right. Start it directly, don't use `cmd.exe /c` - why add the overhead?

Answer (score 1):

That is because `netsh` presents a prompt and expects user input. It must be dealt with in a more complex way.